# How can I convert curl response from salesforce CRM into datagridview on c#?

Tags: c#, json, salesforce, soql

**Below is a curl response from salesforce CRM , would like to show Id, Status, Brand__c, Case_Name__c on DataGridView using c#**

```
{
    "totalSize": 2,
    "done": true,
    "records": [{
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Case",
            "url": "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Case/5001r00002e1X48AAE"
        },
        "Id": "5001r00002e1X48AAE",
        "Status": "Completed",
        "Brand__c": "a0D1r0000178jlfEAA",
        "Case_Name__c": "efg-456"
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Case",
            "url": "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Case/5001r00002e1XAKAA2"
        },
        "Id": "5001r00002e1XAKAA2",
        "Status": "Completed",
        "Brand__c": "a0D1r0000165952EAA",
        "Case_Name__c": "abc-123"
    }]
}
```

Tring to find the answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I *suspect* the terminology you're missing is "deserializing" your JSON response into an object structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DataTable instance and assign it as a data source of your gridview

```
    DataTable dt = new JArray(JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("records")
                  .Select(x => new JObject(((JObject)x).Properties()
                  .Where(x => x.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object))))
                  .ToObject<DataTable>();

   var source = new BindingSource();
   source.DataSource = dt;
   grid.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: small correction      DataTable dt = new JArray(JObject.Parse(result).SelectToken("records")
               .Select(x => new JObject(((JObject)x).Properties()
               .Where(y => y.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object))))
               .ToObject<DataTable>();

                var source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = dt;
                grid.DataSource = source;

Comment: @AhmedYousry What  have you  changed? All I can see that you renamed "json" to "result".

Comment: y => y.Value.Type !